# How to sort column index (name of columns) in DF except the first

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, sorting

I would like to rearrange the df. I need the values to be sorted where the names are adjacent by the number and then the letter.
I need the user to put this in excel for plotting the data.
So I need to sort the column names except for the first column.
I have this df:

```
Time A1 A2 A3 B1 B2 C1 C2 D1 
0    2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
```

And I want the table to be sorted such A1,B1,C1,D1 will be next to each other (different sorting of the column names, by number and then letter)

```
Time A1 B1 C1 D1 A2 B2 C2 A3
0    2  5  7  9  3  6  8  4
```

I managed to sort the indexes by:

```
a = sorted(list(df_mean.loc[:,df_mean.columns != 'Time']), key=lambda x: int(x[1:]) + ord(x[1]))
```

But how could I change the values accordingly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```py
df = df[["Time", *sorted(df.columns[1:], key=lambda x: (int(x[1:]), x[0]))]]
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   Time  A1  B1  C1  D1  A2  B2  C2  A3
0     0   2   5   7   9   3   6   8   4
```